# progressbar para ciclos for em php

Tags: php, jquery

My question is very simple. I have some cycles within other cycles, however, let's imagine it's just one and I want to use a progress bar to only show the progress of this cycle.

I have here code that I am developing, in which I use UIKit, but that is making my head hurt because everything works except the progress bar.

The memory consumption is also a complete exaggeration, because through the task manager I see RAM being completely consumed!

The code I'm using is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="uikit3/css/uikit.min.css" />
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="uikit3/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
    <progress id="progressbar" class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <div id="information" style="width"></div>
    <div id="information2" style="width"></div>
    <?php

    ini_set('memory_limit','16M');

    $total = 1741768;
    $x = 0;

    for($n1=1; $n1 < 15; ++$n1)
    {
      for($n2=($n1+1); $n2<48; ++$n2)
      {
        for($n3=($n2+1); $n3<49; ++$n3)
        {
          for($n4=($n3+1); $n4<50; ++$n4)
          {
            for($n5=($n4+1); $n5<51; ++$n5)
            {
                ++$x;
                $percent = intval($x/$total * 100);

                echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$percent.'"</script>';
                echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information2").innerHTML="'.$x.'"</script>';

                echo '<script>

                    jQuery(function () {

                        var animate = setInterval(function () {

                        window.progressbar && (progressbar.value = "'.$percent.'");

                        if (!window.progressbar || progressbar.value >= progressbar.max) {
                            clearInterval(animate);
                        }

                        },0);

                    });
                </script>';


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
            echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Chaves Geradas!"</script>';
    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I used Google to translate for you, however the answers, if any will be in English.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using PHP? This can be done with Javascript alone if you get `total` somehow. It'd prevent this huge mess of getting those several `<script>` tags created each time the inner-most loop executes.

Comment: Tank you  AbraCadaver, i'm portuguese boy and im not very good with english words... lool

Comment: Yes, i need the code in php because i have the main(principal?) project in php.

Question: Why progressbar not works?
And, any solution for memory ram? RAM being completely consumed!

Thanks